# The react build not working 'npm run build'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have tried everything I fixed all the warning, removed the `/` before static , I tried with putting the homepage address but when I run the index.html it only show the blank page. In inspect element there is nothing in root div. I don't know what I am doing wrong can any one please help me out

```
   import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

AND the app file is-

```
  import React,{Component} from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './assets/css/style.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/css/fontawsome.css';
import './assets/css/skin.css';
import './assets/css/ionicons.min.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; 

//Customer
import Customer from './components/admin/customer/Customer';
import NewCustomer from './components/admin/customer/NewCustomer';


import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import {ProtectedRoute}  from "./components/auth/protected.route";

import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

require('dotenv').config()
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/customer" component={Customer} />

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey, can you show what you do in ReactDOM.render.

Comment: please check its default stuff that gets added when create app

Comment: Try to reduce the complexity of your `App` component back to where it does render, something like "Hello World" and add back in other components until it breaks, then figure out what happens with *that* component.

Comment: I did that and it turns out when I put the exact in route then it doesnt work else it does

Comment: Is it all your routes need the `exact` prop, or any specific route?

Comment: only first '/' because if I dont use this then component attache to '/' route loads with other routs

Comment: its been a year, @JhonCuit did you find your solution? if you found please tell me the solution, i have the same problem help me